# How to trigger event by pressing key?

Tags: javascript

I've created a lame car game in which by clicking a button an image of a car moves to the right a little each time. But now I want to trigger the button by pressing a key. I've used onKeypress and placed it inside the button tag but it isn't working. I tried to figure it out on my own but unfortunately couldn't wrack up the logic for it. Can you guys help me out with this, please?

```
    <div id="racetrack"><img id="user" src="ferrari.jpg"></div>
    <button id="pedal" onkeypress="moveCar()">Pedal</button>

    function moveCar(){
    var car = document.getElementById("user");
    var marginLeft = car.style.marginLeft == "" ? "0px" : car.style.marginLeft;
    car.style.marginLeft = parseInt(marginLeft) + 100 + "px";
```

Comment: can you put the entire code in sandbox, codepen etc.

Answer (score 1):

**See a very simple example below. (Try clicking buttons and hitting left/right arrow keys)**

I think you'd want to attach a general `keydown` event to `window` (or `global`), rather than attaching to the `button`. While you *can* listen for keyboardEvents on a button, you'd need to have the element focused first.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const user = document.querySelector('#user');
let delta = 0;

function move() {
  user.style.transform = `translateX(${delta}px)`;
}
function handleClick(e) {
  const direction = e.target.dataset.id;

  if (direction === 'left') {
    delta += -10;
  } else {
    delta += 10;
  }
  move();
}

function handleKeydown(e) {
  const key = e.code;
  if (key !== 'ArrowLeft' && key !== 'ArrowRight') return;
  if (key === 'ArrowLeft') { 
    delta += -10 
  } else {
    delta += 10;
  }
  move();
}

buttons.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick));
window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown);
```

```css
#racetrack {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#racetrack img {
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.controls {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="racetrack">
  <img id="user" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/">
  <div class="controls">
    <button data-id="left">left</button>
    <button data-id="right">right</button>
  </div>
</div>
```